# JIRA REST API corrupts uploaded zip attachment

Tags: spring, jira, zip, resttemplate, jira-rest-api

I am attempting to use the JIRA Rest API (version 2) to add a zip attachment to an issue.

The code seems to work fine, but when I look at the attached files on the ticket the attachment is almost twice the size it should be, and upon attempting to open it I find it is corrupt.

I can upload an image file (a png in my testing) without an issue.

The code I am using is:

```
String basic = createBasicAuth();
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.add("Authorization", "Basic " + basic);
headers.add("X-Atlassian-Token", "no-check");
headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);

LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Resource> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
map.add("file", new ClassPathResource("/zipfile.zip"));

HttpEntity<LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Resource>> body = new HttpEntity<>(map, headers);

RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.postForEntity(jiraUrl, body, String.class);
```

I have attempted to use a `ByteArrayResource` rather than `ClassPathResource` but this results in a 500 error from the server.

I have also attempted to wrap each resource in their own `HttpEntity`, given the zip file its own headers with the media type set to application/octet-stream.

Has anybody else had this issue?  If not I will log it with Atlassian.
Any help would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this is an issue wither with the Spring (3.2.1) `RestTemplate`, or how I am using it.
Using Postman manually upload the zip file results in a successfully uploaded zip file.